# Azure Service Bus Restful Api Get

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, restful-authentication

I am trying to generate access Azure Service Bus Resftul APIs using SAS. My understanding is I need to generate an `authorization` header with something like the following:-

```
SharedAccessSignature sig=<sig>&
se=<epochexpirydate>&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey&
sr=<urlToQueue>
```

Using postman I try to launch a request to `https://service-bus-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/queuename`

I generate the signature of my SAS using the url from `sr` & `\n` & `epoch-time` encrypted to SHA256 using an online sha256 generator.

However I am always getting 401 SubCode:40103 Invalid authorization token signature. Hoping someone could give me assistance so I can get messages from the queue.

example:

`SharedAccessSignature sig=ab5c0a1b42b96af5ef9cbc85c7088651e9ebf8785d1eeffe6c4955be2c70ca2b&se=7270650090&skn=MyAccessKey&sr=https%3A%2F%2Fnamespace.servicebus.windows.net%2Fqueuename`

Comment: Can you try by changing `/n` in `sr & /n & epoch-time`to `\n`?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS i did mean new line with /n I am doing \n already

Comment: One more thing: Are you URL encoding your `sr`?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I am percent url encoding my sr

Comment: Hmm...Can you share some screenshots or something?

Answer (score 0):

According to the 401 error means that the token is not vaild.

Use the below code to generate the correct SAS Token and then pass the generated token to **Authorization** header:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace App1
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string queueUrl = "TODO"; // Format: "https://<service bus namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<queue name>";
        static readonly string signatureKeyName = "TODO";
        static readonly string signatureKey = "TODO";
        static readonly TimeSpan timeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = GetSasToken(queueUrl, signatureKeyName, signatureKey, timeToLive);
            Console.WriteLine("Authorization: " + token);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static string GetSasToken(string resourceUri, string keyName, string key, TimeSpan ttl)
        {
            var expiry = GetExpiry(ttl);
            string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
            var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);
            return sasToken;
        }

        private static string GetExpiry(TimeSpan ttl)
        {
            TimeSpan expirySinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + ttl;
            return Convert.ToString((int)expirySinceEpoch.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }
}
```